# C program - error: type mismatch with previous external decl of ‘char line []’ [-fpermissive]\

Tags: c, gcc

I am new to c language.  So, I copied code out of Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie 's book(The C programming language).  I was copying pg32 example.  When I got this error:

```
pg32.c: In function ‘int main()’:
pg32.c:16:23: error: type mismatch with previous external decl of ‘char longest []’ [-fpermissive]
pg32.c:7:6: error: previous external decl of ‘char longest [1000]’ [-fpermissive]
pg32.c: In function ‘int getl()’:
pg32.c:33:20: error: type mismatch with previous external decl of ‘char line []’ [-fpermissive]
pg32.c:6:6: error: previous external decl of ‘char line [1000]’ [-fpermissive]
pg32.c: In function ‘void copy()’:
pg32.c:50:20: error: type mismatch with previous external decl of ‘char line []’ [-fpermissive]
pg32.c:6:6: error: previous external decl of ‘char line [1000]’ [-fpermissive]
pg32.c:50:31: error: type mismatch with previous external decl of ‘char longest []’ [-fpermissive]
pg32.c:7:6: error: previous external decl of ‘char longest [1000]’ [-fpermissive]
```

I retype the code 4 time, same error.  I am not sure, but I think it is is a legacy problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int max;
char line[MAXLINE];
char longest[MAXLINE];

int getl(void);
void copy(void);

int main()
{
  int len;
  extern  int max;
  extern char longest[];

  max =0;
  while((len =getl()) > 0)
    if(len > max){
      max = len;
    copy();
    }

  if(max > 0)
    printf("%s", longest);
  return 0;
}

int getl(void)
{
  int c, i;
  extern char line[];

  for(i =0; i < MAXLINE-1 &&
    (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    line[i] =c;

  if(c=='\n'){
    line[i] = c;
    ++i;
  }
  line[i] ='\0';
  return i;
}

void copy(void)
{
  int i;
  extern char line[], longest[];

  i=0;
  while((longest[i] = line[i]) != '\0')
    ++i;
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What compiler are you using? This [compiles](http://ideone.com/7k1Vw) with gcc-4.3.4

Comment: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu4)

Answer (score 2):

You have "line" and "longest" declared as global variables at the top of the file as fixed length arrays.  Then you redeclare them as extern (no need for this by the way) as arrays of indeterminate length.  Compiler is not liking that, so there are 2 solutions:

1. Change every `extern line[]` to `extern line[MAXLINES]` and every `extern char longest[]` to `extern char longest[MAXLINES]`
2. Remove all of your `extern` declarations and just use the globals at the top

Comment: Both should work.  If it's in the same file like this (the actual declaration and the extern declaration), option two is actually preferable in my opinion.

Comment: Option 2 does have an error regarding array size.  But thank you for option 1.